# Maximum current on CD74HC4067

Tags: current, relay, multiplexer

I want to build a smart locker using this part 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32845920160/32845920160.html and a CD74HC4067 multiplexer. Essentially I need to turn on only one lock at time using a relay. I have seen that the lock draws 350mA @ 6 V. Am I risking to burn CD74HC4067 chip? Do you know if there is a multiplexer with higher currents than this?

Comment: Look for the datasheet of the chip. 350mA is a lot for a chip to drive. If only there was some kind of _switch_ that could be _driven by a current/voltage_ to control a _higher current/voltage_...

Comment: You don't want to use anything similar (a multiplexer) for this task. You want a separate power supply for the locks (separate from the controlling electronics), and you either want a mechanical relay or a power transistor/MOSFET to actually switch the lock's current. The relay would automatically give you galvanic separation, and for the other option (transistor/MOSFET), I'd definitely insert an optocoupler into the control path to provide the same galvanic separation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 4067 is an analog multiplexer, not a power switch. It is not designed to supply any significant current to its outputs -- [the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4067.pdf) specifies an "absolute maximum" of:

> DC Output Source or Sink Current per Output Pin: ±25 mA

This is because its intended application is for switching analog signals to high-impedance loads, like operational amplifiers or DACs.

A MOSFET or relay would be a more appropriate choice here.

Comment: Not to be picky, but what is your source for the quote?

Comment: @Sparky256 [From the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4067.pdf). Page 3, near the bottom of the "Absolute Maximum Ratings" section.

Comment: Ok, but you should post the link in your answer. I have been 'chewed out' before for not listing the source of my quotes. Just a heads up.

Comment: @Sparky256 Fair point. Edited. :)

Comment: The small FET switches in that analog mux, probably 100 micron on a side at most (to avoid wasting silicon area) will be just a few microns deep. The thermal time constant of 2 micron channels is about 50 nanoseconds; hence high currents lasting longer than a few nanosecond will simply charge up the thermal mass ---- the FET channel ---- and cause over temperature and likely silicon melting.

Comment: I'm not an electronics expert as you can see :) Can you suggest me a proper solution, different from using a separate relay for every different lock, supposing that only one lock at time should remain opened (lock is normally closed and stay opened if current is applied)

Comment: This is because I want to open a lot of locks (let's say 100) and I don't want to use a separate pin and relay to control them.

Comment: @AlessandroDionisi You'll need a separate relay/power transistor/MOSFET for each of them. Since speed is not an issue here, you can use serial shift registers (like 74HC164 and similar) to spare pins on your microcontroller.